# List.contains() fails while .equals() works

Tags: java, list, equals, contains

I have an `ArrayList` of `Test` objects, which use a string as the equivalency check. I want to be able to use `List.contains()` to check whether or not the list contains an object that uses a certain string.

Simply:

```
Test a = new Test("a");
a.equals("a"); // True

List<Test> test = new ArrayList<Test>();
test.add(a);
test.contains("a"); // False!
```

Equals and Hash function:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) return false;
    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Test)) {
        return (o instanceof String) && (name.equals(o));
    }
    Test t = (Test)o;
    return name.equals(t.GetName());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return name.hashCode();
}
```

I read that to make sure `contains` works for a custom class, it needs to override `equals`. Thus it's super strange to me that while `equals` returns true, `contains` returns false.

How can I make this work?

[Full code](http://ideone.com/sXC06t)

Comment: a class should only test `equals` with the same class.

Comment: Your idea of what `equals` is suppose to do is wrong, you should be comparing `Test` with another instance of `Test`

Comment: only the reverse would work, because `"a".equals(new Test("a")) == false`

Comment: also, the fact that `"a".equals(new Test("a")) != new Test("a").equals("a")` is a problem.

Comment: @bayou.io The contract for `Object.equals` tacitly requires it, due to the commutative property of non-null `equal`ity.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just because your `Test`'s `equals` may return true when you pass a String to it doesn't mean that `String`'s `equals` will ever return true when you pass a `Test` instance to it. In fact, `String`'s `equals` can only return `true` when the instance passed to it is another `String` :

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) { // the passed instance must be a String
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                    return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

`ArrayList`'s `contains` calls `indexOf` which uses the `equals` method of the searched instance (the `String` "a" in your example), not the element type of the `List` (which is `Test` in your case) :

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i])) // o in your case is a String while
                                          // elementData[i] is a Test
                                          // so String's equals returns false
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: `new Test("a").equals("a")` returns true, while `"a".equals(new Test("a"))` returns false, nice explaing! thanks Eran!

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot of sense now. So essentially the only way to solve this (and the only right way to go about this) is to write `test.contains(new Test("a"))`?

Comment: I assume the reason we have `o.equals(elementData[i]` instead of its inverse is because we have a guarantee that `o != null` and we have no such guarantee with the `object[]`?

Comment: @BenKnoble `o` is guaranteed not to be null due to the specific implementation of `indexOf`. An alternative implementation that would also work is to have a single loop that checks if each `elementData[i]` is null or not, and run `elementData[i],equals(o)` if it's not null. That implementation would require more null checks when `o != null`, which might be the reason it wasn't chosen.

Answer (score 27):

`equals()` should always be [*commutative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), i.e. `a.equals(b)` and `b.equals(a)` should always return the same value. Or *symmetric*, as the javadoc of [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) calls it:

> The `equals` method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references:
>
> - It is *reflexive*: for any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(x)` should return `true`.
> - **It is *symmetric*: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return `true` if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns `true`.**
> - It is *transitive*: for any non-null reference values `x`, `y`, and `z`, if `x.equals(y)` returns `true` and `y.equals(z)` returns `true`, then `x.equals(z)` should return `true`.
> - It is *consistent*: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, multiple invocations of `x.equals(y)` consistently return `true` or consistently return `false`, provided no information used in `equals` comparisons on the objects is modified.
> - For any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` should return `false`.

Unfortunately, even the Java Runtime Library gets this one wrong. `Date.equals(Timestamp)` will compare the millisecond values, ignoring the nanoseconds present in the `Timestamp`, while `Timestamp.equals(Date)` returns `false`.

Comment: +1 Keeping the asymmetric `equals` would make the code unnecessarily fragile and hard to maintain because of dependency on which way round tests are done.

Comment: There is even bigger assymetry in JDK - Map interface. If you have ever wondered why Map has get(Object key) instead of get(K key) - exactly to allow passing random classes which happen to have broken equality working against K instances. In one version of java Sun has changed this order (so value inside map was compared to passed key instead of other way around) and it has broken so many applications they had to fall back on that.

Answer (score 19):

The problem is that `List<E>.contains(object o)` is documented to return true:

> > if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

(From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)

Note that it doesn't perform the test as `e.equals(o)` which is what would be necessary for your test to work. Your equals method fails to work commutatively ('symmetrically' using the terms from the Java docs).

Java documents that the `equals()` method for a class must follow these rules:

> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null
>   object references:
>
> - It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(x)` should return true.
> - **It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return true if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns true.**
> - It is transitive: for any non-null reference values `x`, `y`, and `z`, if `x.equals(y)` returns true and `y.equals(z)` returns true, then `x.equals(z)` should return true.
> - It is consistent: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, multiple invocations of `x.equals(y)` consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.
> - For any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` should return false.

Answer (score 5):

If you write

```
test.contains(new Test("a"));
```

then it will surely return true. You are checking for string object in list of Test.

Comment: So we need to create a new object with using `contains` call?